# Images on Blogger private blog

Tags: blogger

I have an idea to create a private blog for my family. My question is, if I upload photos to the private blog, are they visible to anyone in Google search or Google+? If so, how can I make them private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't add google + page on your blog you can blog without google plus so your images are private only your page authors only see that. bBtter avoid  google + share on your blog and also remove your share button on your blog